# How can I convert a string to a byte array?

Tags: c++, string, memory, type-conversion, byte

How can I convert a string to a byte array in C++?

For example, `"Hello"` → `48 65 6c 6c 6f`.

I'm trying to pattern search the memory with this byte array after.

Comment: It is not clear what is the type of the "byte array".

Comment: Which book are you using? You cannot learn the language by randomly flailing about on Google!

Comment: i just want to know how to do a simple thing, i didnt want to buy a book

Comment: @Spoody Well, things that look simple in 1st place might require a book or reference  to explain for completeness though. Also things that are _too simple_ are covered by basics that are covered by a book or online tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

`std::string::c_str()` yields the underlyng c string / byte array.

Also see [**`std::string::c_str()`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) for a list of occasions when the returned pointer might be invalidated (basically everytime you modify the string and of course when the `std::string` itself is destroyed).

You can create a copy of it using `memcpy()` if required.

Comment: `std::string::c_str()` will miss to return bytes after a ´'\0'´.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ std::string::c_str() will correctly return a pointer that is a byte array. It is up to the caller of the code to take into account any null characters and use, say, a count instead. But it will in fact return a byte array.

Comment: @Altainia Well, I thought the [`std::string::data()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) should be more appropriate here.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ `data()` is the same as `c_str()` since 11